# get total result from google search using REST to invoke API

Tags: php, google-search-api

hI, I could not get this right.
I would like to get the totalResults from this returned json result
full text: http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/using_rest.html

```
  "request": [
   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - flowers",
    "totalResults": 10300000,
    "searchTerms": "flowers",
   }
  ]
 },
```

i tried this:

```
$response = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=flowers&alt=json
');
$json = json_decode($response);
echo "Total Result:".$json->request->totalResults;
```

but i got nothing.
Need help pls. Thanks.

Comment: Did you insert your key where it says `INSERT-YOUR-KEY`?

Comment: yes I did insert the api key. just dont know how to display only the totalResults;

Answer (score 1):

In your post it's not visible all the json. In my tests it works with this:

> $json->queries->request[0]->totalResults;

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try an if(!is_null($json->request->totalResults)) conditional to see if you're even getting a response.

Comment: I am getting a response and the response structure pattern is in json and similar to this url ; http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/using_rest.html `code$json->request->totalResults`code doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I grabbed the JSON from the Google page you linked to and this worked for me: `code`$json->queries->request[0]->totalResults

Comment: ok.. thanks. now I know how to get it.. Thanks a lot @jondbaker